# How to get JMSMessageId after sending it with an outbound-channel-adapter?

Tags: spring-integration

I am sending a JMS message with the outbound channel adapter like this:

```
<intjms:outbound-channel-adapter
      destination-name="MY.QUEUE"
      connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
      channel="mySender"/>
```

After this I need to know the JMS Message Id. How can I get it?

[There is](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/remoting/30397-jmsmessageid-after-message-is-sent) a way to do it in a custom `JmsTemplate` I could provide in the adapter, but maybe there is a simpler solution for this problem.

I can not use the gateway because there is no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send JMS `Message` as a `payload` of Spring Integration Message to that adapter. And use its `getJMSMessageID()` after successful sending.

**UPDATE**

> But this means I can not use the convencience of the JmsTemplate and have to deal with javax.jms.Connection and javax.jms.Session on my own to be able to create a javax.jms.Message, correct?

Well, no one forbid you to use even `JmsTemplate` directly as a reference from the general `<service-activator>`. The `<outbound-channel-adapter>` is **one-way** by the goal. So it is really not intended to return anything. Your corner case really requires something to do. And that is the `javax.jms.Session` hooks and tricks to create a JMS Message to be able to retrieve its `ID` afterwards. There is a `ThreadLocal` hole over the custom `JmsHeaderMapper` and the message access from its `fromHeaders()` implementation, but I think that for this case it would be better to use `JmsTemplate` directly.

Comment: But this means I can not use the convencience of the `JmsTemplate` and have to deal with `javax.jms.Connection` and `javax.jms.Session` on my own to be able to create a `javax.jms.Message`, correct?

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.